# Find all occurrences of a word in a file and add a string to them?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file containing my source code for a project I'm working on at the moment.

I have the word `resolution` scattered over the file, and want to prefix it with `self`.

```
--snippet--

resolution = readString[:16]
resolution = resolution.replace("\"", "")

--snippet--
```

How can I do this?

Python, sed, grep, awk, anything...

Comment: In Idle, simply use Ctrl+H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/resolution/self.&/g' some/file
```

Though perhaps you should start using an IDE and its refactoring tools.

If `resolution` could be part of word (say you had `resolutionFoo`), use word boundary markers:

```
sed -i 's/\bresolution\b/self.&/g' some/file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s/resolution/self.&/g|x' file
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `g` replace all instances in each line
4. `x` save and close